# All of the disqus comments are showing up on all the blog pages

Tags: django, disqus

I've built a blog type app. in django. And I'm trying to integrate DISQUS for comments using [montylounge's django-disqus](http://github.com/montylounge/django-disqus). But comments from all the blog posts are showing up on every blog page. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Have you implemented Olly's suggestion, and if so, would you be willing to share your solution and maybe contribute it back to django-disqus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how the django module integrates, but from a Disqus point of view it sounds like you're not setting a unique value for the "disqus_identifier" variable on each page.

You need to have the variable instantiated like this:

```
var disqus_identifier = 'blogpost_<BLOG POST ID HERE>';
```

**before** you include the disqus javascript files.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. In my case, it solved my problem similar to yours. Cheers!

var disqus_url = 'yoursite_dot_com/path_to/id-of-blog-post';

var disqus_identifier = '/id-of-blog-post/';

Answer (score 1):

I think you should view page source code.
Check `disqus_url` - is it an absolute URL?

In `django-disqus` often written like this: `{% set_disqus_url object.get_absolute_url %}`
but `object.get_absolute_url` is your settings.