# How to integrate a django-disqus app into a blog

Tags: django, comments, disqus

Hi my client is desperate to integrate django disqus into the blog we have built for them.  I stumbled upon https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus django disqus app and couldnt believe my luck, i had this up and running in no time, everything appears to be working ok, im posting comments etc however it dosent seem to be identifying properly as a comment posted with object.id for one blog post appears for all posts through out the blog.

in the index template that lists all the blog posts out i have

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% set_disqus_identifier entry.id %}
    {% set_disqus_url entry.get_absolute_url %}
    {% set_disqus_developer 1 %}
    {% blog stuff goes here %}
{%endfor%}
```

in the article template i have

```
{% set_disqus_identifier entry.id %}
{% set_disqus_url entry.get_absolute_url %}
{% set_disqus_developer 1 %}

<section id="comments">
<a href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}#disqus_thread" data-disqus-identifier="{{ entry.id }}">View Comments</a>
<h1>{% disqus_num_replies %}</h1>
<article class="comment">
{% disqus_dev %}
{% disqus_show_comments entry.get_absolute_url %}
```

the problem as i mentioned before is that if i post one comment disqus is applying that to all the blog posts.  I guess im doing something wrong with the identifiers, but when i view source the javascript is getting the right id for each blog post

I really need this to work so will be eternally grateful for any help or advice that has got this working

Comment: is this code copy pasted? This looks like a typo `{% set_disqus_indentifier entry.id %}`

Comment: @DTing i think i typed it actually, im being stupid i cant see the typo :S have you had any experience in getting this app working with django?

Comment: `indentifier` is almost the same as `identifier` =). Sorry i looked into it a bit before and decided against using it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634790/all-of-the-disqus-comments-are-showing-up-on-all-the-blog-pages might be of interest to you. The subtle bold text at the bottom says that the identifier needs to be established before the disqus javascript, not much of your code is shown so its hard to tell whats going on. Good Luck with the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

in your index template, you don't need to do all this set_* stuff. So just load the dev tag to enable local development:

```
{% disqus_dev %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% blog stuff goes here %}
{% endfor %}
```

In your article template just do this to display the comments. The disqus javascript will use the current URL as the identifier, so there's no need to set it manually:

```
{% disqus_show_comments %}
```

Don't forget to set the settings to the correct values as described in the documentation: http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configuring-your-django-installation And also change the url of your Site object to your actual domain.

Comment: AH i missed that last step about the site objects!! thanks ill give that a try.  So when using the app on a production server are there different steps required? just to re-cap
load the disqus_tags
declare disqus_dev tag for development server
then to simply show the comments use
disqus_show_comments

will i need to define the disqus_dev tag above the show_comments again? or is there somewhere more global that it can be defined in the templates??

Thanks so much for your help ill let you know how i get on!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not set the identifier and other values in index template. Because of the for loop its overriding the previous values. Rather, you should set the values in template related to particular post. That way, you would be setting disqus parameters for that particular post.

Note: django-disqus has newer version now, with django 1.7 support.